# Very simple html/css centering trouble

Tags: html, center

I just spent like an hour on something very, very simple. I use to work with HTML and CSS a long time ago but have since then forgotten how to use it. What I need to do is center the div that has the media player inside it.

All feedback is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            h1 {
                text-align:center;
            }
            #vid {

            }
        </style>
        <body>
            <h1>Pysch Season 6 Episode 1</h1>
            <h1>Shawn Rescues Darth Vader</h1>
            <div id="vid">
                <OBJECT id="vid" CLASSID="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B" 
                    CODEBASE="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab" WIDTH="700" HEIGHT="500" >
                    <PARAM NAME="src" VALUE="lol.mp4" >
                    <PARAM NAME="autoplay" VALUE="true" >
                    <EMBED SRC="lol.mp4" TYPE="image/x-macpaint" 
                    PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download" WIDTH="700" HEIGHT="500" AUTOPLAY="true"></EMBED>
                </OBJECT>
            </div>
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where can we download lol.mp4?

Comment: You don't need to download the file to know how to center it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the display to block, and then left and right margins to auto.

```
#vid
{
    Display: block;
    Margin-right: auto;
    Margin-left: auto;
}
```

Comment: this works too. thank you. im going to use this one instead just because its more simple to understand

Comment: the `display: block` is unnecessary since `div`-s are block elements

Comment: I had to include the display:block. if I don't then it doesn't work.

Comment: I had put it in as good practice, I'll re-edit to include again.

Answer (score 2):

```css
#vid {
    width: 700px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```